# If cycle: Javascript and JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, if-statement

```
<script>
...
if(i==0){
<% out.print("current date: " + now) %>
}else{}
</script>
```

This is my script: i pass a value to a function and if the value is 0 it print the current date on the screen. I can't understand why this function print out the date also if i is not 0.

Comment: Please don't write code like this.  Scriptlets do not belong in JSPs.  This is a 90s style that failed.  Learn JSTL if you must write them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a value need to be displayed in window, use a HTML element.

```
<span id='displayvalue'></span>
```

And in script add the value from JSP to the above span.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
...
if(i==0){
document.getElementById('displayvalue').innerHTML = <% out.print("current date: " + now) %>;
}else{
//do something
}
</script>
```